# static initialization in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that is used to store other class' instance objects. The class has the following class method that is called whenever I need to get the class itself (and to its data structure that stores other class' instances, to its methods that operate on the data structure):

```
+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;

//Do I need to create a sharedStore?
if (!sharedStore) {
    sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
}

return sharedStore;
}
```

The line `static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;` is very confusing to me. The first time the class method is called, we declare `static BNRItemStore *sharedStore` and set it to `nil`. I do not understand why if we call the method second time, `sharedStore` is not overwritten and/or deallocated. Apparently, this never happens and all the subsequent calls to the `+ (instancetype)sharedStore()` method seem like completely ignore the line `static BNRItemStore *sharedStore = nil;`. Why is that?

Comment: That's because of the forty year old rules for static variables. The initialisation happens _once_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**static**

Finally, one that everyone’s sure to recognize: static.

As a keyword, static gets used in a lot of different, incompatible ways, so it can be confusing to figure out exactly what it means in every instance. When it comes to storage classes, static means one of two things.

A static variable inside a method or function retains its value between invocations.
A static variable declared globally can be called by any function or method, so long as those functions appear in the same file as the static variable. The same goes for static functions.
Static Singletons

A common pattern in Objective-C is the static singleton, wherein a statically-declared variable is initialized and returned in either a function or class method. dispatch once is used to guarantee that the variable is initialized exactly once in a thread-safe manner:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
  static id _sharedInstance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      _sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
  });

  return _sharedInstance;
}
```

The singleton pattern is useful for creating objects that are shared across the entire application, such as an HTTP client or a notification manager, or objects that may be expensive to create, such as formatters.

source: http://nshipster.com/c-storage-classes/

Answer (score 0):

Objective C does not implement class instance variables. The static declaration keeps sharedStore around permanently, but limits it's access (compared to declaring it outside the class). So there is only one sharedStore and it is initialized only once. Subsequent calls the method simply have access to sharedStore, they don't make new versions of it (nor re-initialize it).